# React Native Circular Progress on Long Press

Tags: react-native, animation, mobile, progress-bar, long-press

I am new in React Native and I am facing difficulty in designing the circular progress bar on long-press a button.

[image]

Here is the design I want to implement. On long press for 5 seconds on the middle red circle, the outer progress bar will be filled with different segment color as shown in the design. Will be a great help if I can be provided with a suggestion to create this design.